# Does Alchemical Allocation work on extracts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Does [Alchemical Allocation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alchemical-allocation) allow you to consume an extract on the round following the consumption of this extract [Alchemical Allocation], spit it [the other extract] back into its container as a free action, gaining all the benefits of the extract, but without it being consumed?

Comment: As a note, it would be appreciated, and likely receive better vote ratings, if future questions contained more than "link (quote) link (quote) (brief obscure sentence that might imply a question)". In general, the question should be easy to understand without the title, and should contain a question somewhere before the supporting material. Also note that it is unnecessary (and sometimes discouraged) to quote blocks of rules text unless it is necessary to point to a confusing portion of text.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I edited it to conform to your recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Alchemical Allocation works on potions and elixirs. An extract uses some of the same rules as potions and elixirs, but an extract is neither a potion nor an elixir.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, because it addresses the fact that potions and extracts are not the same. I've seen more than a couple people ask on other sites if the Accelerated Drinker trait from Cheliax, Empire of Devils applies to extracts as well, because most people think "Well, they're just potions, right?"

Answer (score 2):

A level 2 extract is never going to give a free reuse of a higher level extract. It makes no sense from a game design standpoint. You are correct that Alchemical Allocation does not work on extracts; this is working as intended.